# iphone 4 has a GPS antenna yes or no?

Tags: iphone-4

Can somebody confirm that without wifi or 3G connection, the iphone 4 can get coordinates from GPS ?
On my iphone 4 i tested and i doesn't seem to work.
On my ipad, i tested and without wifi or 3G i got the blue dot moving on maps.

Comment: This strikes me as a question for Google/Apple's site's search box rather than Stack Overflow?

Comment: Try this on http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it might take up to 5 minutes to acqure coordinates.